# Problems with facebook connect

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I am developing an application, which gives the user an option to share feeds using facebook connect. I am stuck at the start itself. I dowloaded the FBConnect sdk and implemented the code as explained in the documentation. Now when the fconnect button is touched in the application, instead of connect page opening, to grant the application permission, the facebook login page opens. Signing on to this page directs the user to facebook home. The facebook window never closes and the application doesn't get permission.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by `[FBSession session]` not being a valid session.

I had this problem and it turned out to be because the session object had been deallocated. When you set the global session by calling `[FBSession setSession:session]` or if you initialize any FBSession object, FBSession doesn't retain it as it should, so make sure you retain the session object even if you don't actually use it or even keep a reference to it. If the session *is* there, make sure your api key and secret are correct.